# how to get use exterior semi transparent on 2 different woods to match each other

Tags: staining

I'm creating two exterior wood furniture one has cedar red and the other one is regular cedar I need to stain both to match each other How do I go about this

Answer (score 3):

The best way to achieve what you want is to experiment with scrap off cuts of both of the types of wood that you used. There is no given recipe for this because different wood samples and stain products are going to work differently.

Even wood samples from the same wood species can work different based upon factors including how dry the wood is, the density of the grain, sap wood versus heart wood and on and on.